# Origins of the adjective ‘inanis’

Tags: etymology

According to *Wiktionary* and De Vaan’s *Etymological Dictionary*, the etymology of the Latin adjective *inanis* (‘empty’; ‘worthless’) is unknown.

I was wondering if anybody had a theory on the origin of this mysterious word; any ideas?

By the way, could it be possible that *inanis* is composed of the prefix *in-* (‘not’) and **anis* (‘full’, ‘useful’?)?

Comment: Other people have tried to connect it with *vānus* (with the *in-* then being an intensifier rather than privative) or *animus* (semantically less convincing). It's possible to construct plausible forms, it's just that there are no parallels in other languages.

Answer (score 9):

I think it could be useful for you to take a look at the following [article](https://lettres.sorbonne-universite.fr/sites/default/files/media/2020-05/dll_14_b._garcia-hernandez.pdf) by Prof. Benjamín García-Hernández. According to him, "*inanis* has its origins in the negation of the substantive *ānus* 'surrounding ring', so that *inānis* has come to mean 'empty', through metonymy from 'without a ring'". See pages 9-11 of the article above (**Section 2.1**) for more discussion.

García-Hernández, Benjamín (2017). «La negación como modalidad alterna.
El *in-* privativo con bases nominales y el origen de *inānis* e *ingens* », *De Lingua Latina, Revue de linguistique latine du Centre Alfred Ernout* 14: 1-16.

Comment: I dont believe anyone in historical ling is at all thrilled with the Garcia-Hernandez idea. However, there is an earlier article by Klingenschmitt, who was a very regarded scholar, which perhaps some do like. I have not read it yet myself. In general,the issue is methodological, or rather issues. First, given the sound laws of Latin, there are numerous theoretically possible sources. Second, we need to have some idea what the principles are that are used (not always consistently) in coming up with acceptable etymologies.

Comment: What was Klingenschmitt's hypothesis?

Comment: That article contains a remarkably bad etymology for *ingens* for having been written in 2017.

Comment: Klingenschmitt, Gert 1994 Die Verwandtschaftsverhältnisse der indogermanischen Sprachen. In: Jens E. Rasmussen (ed.), In honorem Holger Pedersen. Kolloquium der Indogermanischen Gesellschaft vom 26. bis 28. März 1993 in Kopenhagen. Wiesbaden: Reichert.  https://reichert-verlag.de/en/9783882268232_in_honorem_holger_pedersen-detail (pp. 235-251)

Comment: I haven't read Klingenschmitt 1994 yet (pp. 242-243) but in LIV they mention his proposal s.v. *h2es- 'satt werden', "lat. in-anis 'nüchtern; leer' < *n̥-h2es-ni-